# WCF Direct Authentication using BasicHttpBinding

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services

I am trying to  test a simple scenario in my development machine wherein I have a service which is configured on basicHttpbinding. I am trying to use CustomUserNamePasswordValidator and have configured Security level as "TransportWithMessageCredential"

Now, when I test the service with a web client (both service and client on Asp.net development server), service completely ignores the validator and simply returns the data, although I am passing wrong credentials from my client.

Is it because I am using VS Development Server ?
Is use of SSL over HTTP manadatory when we use TransportWithMessageCredentials. Is there an alternative wherein I need not use Https ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF does not support any configurations out of the box which would permit transmission of unsecured credentials.

Comment: Yes, I got the solution. Well the reason that WCF ignored my configuration was because of incorrect service name in web.config file and after that it gave me an error that said "The provided URI scheme 'http' is invalid; expected 'https'".